# Removing Duplicate lines with random text behind it

Tags: notepad++

I have text like this in Notepad++

```
Random Text Here:188.0.0.0
Random Text Here:188.0.3.0
Random Text Here:188.2.0.0
```

However, some of the numbers at the end are duplicated and I am wanting to get rid of them. For example:

```
Random Text Here:188.0.3.0
Random Different Text Here:188.0.3.0
```

How would I go about doing that in the mass's as there are thousands of these lines?

Comment: Uh, do you want to keep the *second* line? Why not the first or the last? Also, in your example, not the numbers are duplicated, but the text *before*  the numbers (IP address?) is. Can you clarify?

Comment: You can't just get rid of duplicate numbers - in my oppinion, the text before the delimiter (:) and after it create a key, which identifies the entry. Only if entire lines are duplicates of existing lines (not regarding possible timestamps, I'd consider removing them.

Comment: Sorry, should have explained it better. It's the IP that is duplicated, not the text before the IP. I'm wanting to get rid of dublicate IP's but the random text is getting in the way from me doing it.

I'd like this:
Random Text Here:188.0.3.0
Random Different Text Here:188.0.3.0

To be left with:
Random Text Here:188.0.3.0

As the second one is the same IP.

Comment: Has you question been answered? If so then please accept the answer. If not then what more is wanted?

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++ I would try the following multi-step process.

(1) Use a regular expression to change all lines to put the IP address and fixed text at the front from `Random Text Here:188.0.0.0` to `:188.0.0.0!!!Random Text Here`.

(2) Use TextFx to sort the file removing duplicates.

(3) Use a regular expression to find and remove duplicate. This may need multiple passes.

(4) Use a regular expression to put the text back in the right order.

(5) (Optional) sort the file again.

Problems with the above approach:

(a) The "random text" that sorts first for an IP address will be the one that is kept, not the first in the original file.

(b) The result will be ordered by IP address or by the random text depending on whether step (5) is used.

In more detail:

(0) Choose a character or a short string that does not occur in the input file. I will use `!!`.

(1) Do a regular expression replace on the file (with dot **does not** match newline selected) to change `^(.*)(:\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$` to `$2!!$1`.

(2) Use TextFx to sort the file. Specifying sort unique may be useful to reduce the number of lines.

(3) Do a regular expression replace on the file (with dot **does not** match newline selected) to change `^(:\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)!!(.*)\r\n\1.*$` to `$1!!$2`. When there are several lines with the same IP address this will remove about half of them. Run the same replacement several times until it reports no changes have been made. You may need to alter the `\r\n` part depending on the line endings in your file

(4) Do a regular expression replace on the file (with dot **does not** match newline selected) to change `^(:\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)!!(.*)$` to `$2$1`.

(5) (Optional) sort the file again.