# If duplicate within brackets, delete one of the lines

Tags: regex, text, formatting, notepad++, sublimetext

Hi i have a long list of items (~6k), that comes in this format:

```
'Entry': ['Entry'],
```

What i want to do, is if within the first bracket, the words match, i.e.:

```
'ACT': ['KOSOV'],

'ACT': ['STIG'],
```

I want it to leave only one of the entries, it doesn't matter which entry the first the second or whatever, i just need it to leave one of them.

If possible I would like to accomplish that by sublime, or notepad++ using regexp and if there is no way then do whatever you think is best to solve this.

UPD:  The AWK command did the job indeed, thank you

Comment: where is the match ? i dont think `KOSOV` and `STIG` can match

Comment: the ACT part is the match, thats the problem if the lines were identical then it would be a matter of few clicks

Comment: anybody is missing awk? `awk -F: '!a[$1]++' file` does the job. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551526/removing-duplicate-lines-with-random-text-behind-it

Comment: if so, i have no idea how to apply ^(GUID:\s*\d+\r\n)\1,  to my current issue of search for duplicates within the first set of '' brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't solve this using just regular expressions. You either need to remember all entries you've seen so far while scanning the text (would require writing a small utility program, probably), or you could sort the entries and then remove any repeated entries.

If you have a sorted file, then you can solve it using a regular expression, such as this one:

```
^(([^:]+):.+\n)(?:\2.+\n)+
```

Replace with `\1`. See it in action [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=82bf6b62-3911-4a3a-9254-c1df82efc1a0)